# DevExpress XPO NonPersistentAttribute vs ObjectProperties

Tags: devexpress, xpo

All properties of `XPObject` descendant class which are foreign keys pointing to another `XPObject` entities are easily available under `ObjectProperties` property. I have manually added a custom property to my class which type is a `XPObject` child and marked it as `[NonPersistent]`.

Now I am writing some generic code and would like to iterate through all properties of type being a `XPObject` child - no matter if they are persistent or not. Is the `Members` property (property filtered) the only option?

I am not very happy with that approach, I expect much filtering and casting to get what I  need.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented my requirement using `Members` property. The aim is to do some formatting actions for `GridView` columns if property type is a `XPObject` descendant implementing `IMyInterface`.
The code looks as follows:

```
classInfo.Members
    .Where(m => m.IsPublic && m.ReferenceType != null && typeof(IMyDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(m.ReferenceType))
    .OfType<XPMemberInfo>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach( prop =>
    {
        // doing what needs to be done
    };
```

It seems to work fine. Anyway I'd be really happy to see a more straightforward approach.